# How to disable ios momentum scrolling in ionic 2

Tags: ios, angular, ionic2

I have an ionic2 app with a virtual list. This list has a search feature. If the user enters a search term while the virtual list is still scrolling, some results don't filter correctly. Is it possible to disable the scrolling momentum so that the moment a user lets go the scrolling stops?